# How to import Google material design icon in android studio 3.2.1 latest version?

Tags: android, google-material-icons

I am using Google material design icon for my web application from [google material design icon](https://github.com/google/material-design-icons). We are creating a new android application for same.so for each icon i need to download its resources and manually copying and paste png to the respective resolution. Which is very hectic task of copying and pasting the icons.  Is there is way in android i can import it as plugin in android studio ? i have to added so many icons in the app.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can use third party `IntelliJ` plugin like [`material design icon generator`](https://github.com/konifar/android-material-design-icon-generator-plugin)

for Installation

On MAC:

> - Go Preference > Plugins > Browse repositories, then search material.

On Linux or Windows:

> - Go File > Settings> Plugins > Browse repositories, then search material.

Comment: I m using Windows

Comment: Go File > Settings> Plugins > Browse repositories, then search material.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, there is a Plugin for Material Icons!

Just go through this link - https://github.com/konifar/android-material-design-icon-generator-plugin

Answer (score 3):

Yes , You can install Material Design Icon Generator plugin in android studio. 
From there you can get the all material design icons.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you are right you have to do it manually by downloading one by one from 

[MaterialDesignIcons](https://materialdesignicons.com/)
 or 
 Generate Icons using
[Material Design Icons Generator Plugin](https://github.com/konifar/android-material-design-icon-generator-plugin) with Android Studio.

But there is an open source solution available related to your problem but its outdated one and icons might be less.

[DroidIcon](https://github.com/theDazzler/droidicon)

[Installation Guide of DroidIcon for Android](https://github.com/theDazzler/droidicon/wiki/How-to-Use)

Comment: Thanks harsh, Your answer really helps